# How do I run JUnit tests in a Docker container and have the container fail startup when JUnit fails?

Tags: maven, junit, docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose

I want to run Junit tests in a Docker container, and have the container fail if the tests fail.

In my Docker file I have :

```
FROM maven:3.2-jdk-7-onbuild
CMD mvn verify
```

I'm kicking this off from a Go CI server running a docker compose command.

What I'm seeing is that this starts a background thread of execution and the tests start running - and the Go CI server gets an OK - just as the maven process has started. The test finishes running with some failures, but by then the Go server has already displayed a green "all good" status.

Part of the problem is I need the `EXEC` command to block until the tests have finished running.

My question is: **How do I run JUnit tests in a Docker container and have the container fail startup when JUnit fails?**

Comment: The container can't fail..cause it's separated...Why do you like to run your unit tests in a container? Sounds like you are trying to run integration tests instead...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `docker-compose run` instead of `docker-compose up`.

`run` will block, and exit with the same exit status as the process in the container.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful - but I'm not seeing `run` do a blocking behaviour for `docker-compose run`. It's working like `docker-compose up -d` (ie daemon-like)

Comment: hmm, only `run -d` should do that, so I'm not sure what you're seeing. Could you include some output?